# Umount: target is busy to variable

Tags: shell-script, variable, variable-substitution, error-handling, unmounting

I want to check if a USB is busy and store the result in a variable:

```
$ foo=$(umount /dev/sdb1)
$ umount: /path/mounted: target is busy.
```

But when I want to print `$foo`, I get an empty variable

```
$ echo $foo
$
```

My final goal is to umount the USB. If the target is busy, issue a warning to the user, using `whiptail`. So:

```
$ [[ -z $foo ]] || whiptail --msbox "Cancel the operation that is maintaining your USB busy" 0 0
```

Is it possible to store the error `target is busy` on a variable, or should I use another kind of technique?

Comment: `umount /dev/sdb1 || whiptail` should work.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks, it seems that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programs commonly write error messages to the “standard error” I/O stream;
“stderr” for short. 
If you search for that term, you’ll gets millions of results;
the short explanation is that stderr exists so error messages can and will
go to the screen when the “standard output” (“stdout”) is redirected,
as in a hypothetical command like

```
umount /dev/sdb1 > um.result.txt
```

And you can see this happening; the error message appears on your screen
even though you are trying to capture it in a variable.

The equally short answer is to use `2>&1`
to merge the stderr stream into the stdout stream, so

```
foo=$(umount /dev/sdb1 2>&1)
```

will capture the error message in the variable.

Another approach, [as suggested by jordanm in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/539282/80216#comment1000509_539282),
is to look at the exit status. 
Variations on this theme include:

```
umount /dev/sdb1  ||  complain to user
```

```
if ! umount /dev/sdb1
then
    complain to user
fi
```

```
umount /dev/sdb1 2> /dev/null  ||  complain to user
```

```
 foo=$(umount /dev/sdb1 2>&1)  ||  complain to user using "$foo"
```

Comment: @tsul: Thanks for doing that research and sharing your results.

Comment: (Facepalm!) And I should have noticed the flaw in `sh -c "<command>; echo $?"`. Yeah; if your comments are wrong, delete them.